# ITS_CANT_LOAD_INCLUDE "Template interpretation terminated, syntax error"

Tags: html, abap, sap-gui, handheld

We have this trouble:

We have been changing styles in our ITS Mobile applications, due to we have acquired new handhelds which are Android and the one we are replacing are Windows OS.

We have always used the WebGui style but the new handhelds with Android can't show popups and that's why we are transforming the styles to MOBILE4 and because, according to SAP, WebGui style is obsolete now.

The problem is that, when testing in Q&A, we are having dumps when we access the applications through handhelds, both Windows and Android.

The dumps show this:

> The template zitsmobile\99\zmm_dynnr_50.html 
> contains syntax errors and therefore could not be compiled. Cause of 
> error: Include "include/sound" does not exist 
> The syntax error is in row: 50, column: 87 
> The HTMLB row with errors is: 
> "   include(~service="itsmobile", ~language="", ~theme="99", 
> ~name="include/sound.html");"

We tried to change the style to just MOBILE but dump is another message:

> The template zitsmobile\99\zmm_dynnr_50.html 
> contains syntax errors and therefore could not be compiled. Cause of 
> error: Include "include/sound" does not exist 
> The syntax error is in row: 33, column: 87 
> The HTMLB row with errors is: 
> "   include(~service="itsmobile", ~language="", ~theme="99", 
> ~name="include/sound.html");"

Screen:

> 500 Internal Server Error 
> Template interpretation terminated, syntax error.

UPDATE:

We tried to change the style and problems in that server arose.

In fact, we notice that template `RLMENU` `2888` file is different in between Q&A environment and production environment.

If we try to regenerate template `RLMENU` `2888` then all the other applications trigger dumps.

So, regenerating template `RLMENU` `2888` makes it worse.

We are really confused of what to do in this case.

[image: RLMENU 2888]

Comment: I see that you are not positioning the ending backticks correctly (at least not like in production), you don't include the end of line.

Comment: Hi@SandraRossi. Thanks for the response. We don't edit anything at all. This is SAP generated code and the same file in different clients. The Q&A code was generated recently and the PRD code as generated in 2011. Of course there have been patches installed all these years and maybe that is the cause but, recently we tried to transport the QA order of this new generated to PRD and it was a mess. We had to return to the original version in PRD. Now we're stuck here cause we can't update these handheld apps because of these issues.

Comment: Did you check if there are some patches, or did you contact SAP support? They can investigate directly in your system.

Comment: No, I haven't. Is this issue suitable to submit to SAP support? Didn't know that. 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally fixed the issue.

The cause of the problem was that the ITSMOBILE internet service was not published in production.

[image]

When we published it finally the resource INCLUDE/SOUND and the rest were available.

However we had an issue after publishing.

We had to apply the SAP Note 2221538 - ITS_UNEXPECTED_TOKEN or ITS_UNDEFINED_NAT_FUNCTION dumps in ITSmobile application because there was a dump were we had to add declare the sh() function in INCLUDE/CUAAREA.html in ITSMOBILE.

The error in dump was ITS_UNDECLARED_FUNCTION.

[image]